# Checking for Null Values in CRM 2011 Custom Workflow Activity

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I am trying to perform some logic in a CRM 2011 Custom Workflow Activity with some attributes from the calling entity. I am having an issue with determining whether a particular attribute is null or not. I have tried seemingly all combinations of GetAttributeValue and the Attributes collection, but it seems that I will always get either a Specified Cast is not Valid or Object Reference Not Set to an Instance of an Object error when there is a null value for an attribute I'm trying to access. Does anyone know the correct method for accessing an attribute that may be null? In this example, I am working with attributes of the Guid/Entity Reference type.

Answer (score 0):

You can always check to see if the attributes collection contains the specific attribute that you're looking for, but you shouldn't even have to do that.  All Non-nullable types (Guid, DateTime, etc) are stored as nullable types in the Attributes collection and that's probably your problem.  Try something like this ( assuming late bound):

`var isValid = entity.GetAttributeValue<bool?>("new_IsValid");`

CRM never returns a non-nullable value.   Even things that you think would be null (bool, DateTime, int, etc) are returned as their nullable equivalent.  A non-nullable cast will still succeed if the value is not null, but if the value is null, it'll give you a null reference error;

```cs
object a = new bool?(true);
bool value = ((bool)a); // Works 
object b = new bool?();
bool value = ((bool)b); // Null Ref Error
```

Comment: This worked for detecting null values, but with non-null values I get a specified cast is not valid error.

Comment: @user1603734 that's because they are Nullable types, and not `bool`, `DateTime`, `int`, etc. but `bool?` (aka `Nullable<bool>'), 'DateTime?' and 'int?'.

Comment: So how can I make this be able to handle both null and non-null values? This seems to be the problem I keep running into, syntax for detecting one causes an error with the other.

Answer (score 0):

This syntax ended up working for me:

```
//if current outside counsel not null, grab GUID value
  if (thisCase.lgl_outsidecounselid != null)
  {
  currentOCGUID = thisCase.lgl_outsidecounselid.Id;
  }
//it's null, set Guid to Guid.empty
  else
  {
  currentOCGUID = Guid.Empty;
  }
```